# com.apple.xyz.plist - replace value - not set key - possbile?

Tags: applescript, bash, xcode, plist

I've looked into using **PlistBuddy** and **plutil** but most examples such as:

[How do I replace a value in an plist array using plutil?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282732/how-do-i-replace-a-value-in-an-plist-array-using-plutil)

seem to suggest **setting** the value of a **key**, which is not the case here.

I want to modify a **value** I do not know exists or not. See, I don't know what the key is. I want to automate it.

So if you can search for a value, get the **value** and **key** then I could possibly use the above to set a new value on the key.

But i have not figured out a way to do that.

Do you know? Preferably in **Bash**.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the property list data you'll be working with and highlight where the value of interest sits ?

Comment: @CJK No, I can not. The value could be in 10-30 files and I can not make any assumptions and generally I would refuse to make solutions around a particular use case, or understood use case. Either way, I've already solved it. I will be posting the answer later here.

Comment: Well done for solving it. For future reference, sample data isn't requested to tailor a solution specifically to a single use case. It's asked for one or more of these reasons:

Comment: to better illustrate the nature of the question and reduce back-and-forth for clarification; to give an _example_ use case that provides a starting point for testing purposes; to help reduce workload by sparing the need for the programmer to "invent" their first data set, and the pain of typing out what could be pasted; to give a common dataset all users can use to correlate their solution against others early; to propose a different approach to the problem that might be simpler/faster/more generalised by first mutating the data in a specific way; other reasons, probably worthy albeit opaque

Comment: abc.plist ... contains: aaa bbb ccc ddd aaa bbb ccc; Now I wish to replace the value aaa with whatever i desire.

Comment: `abc.plist` would not be a valid property list file. It would be a text file, which makes replacement trivial once you clarified which occurrence(s) of the string you wanted to replace.  Also, made up data is more difficult to work with. Of course, you have no obligation to employ any of these tips, but the type, amount and quality of help you end up receiving could make a demonstrable difference to you in the end.  Look forward to seeing how you solved it, which I'm sure will be a great help for others facing a similar dilemma.

Comment: I think you will never understand a pseudo example. That example is all you have to consider, not if it is valid syntax or not. That's the example. Whatever is in that file. I've already solved it, so no need to keep going on. I think you understand that example perfectly and should be enough, but choose to try to educate me on how to write a question. I don't need to tell my use case, why i need it, what why I think i need it, and so forth. All i know is I want to replace a value with something else in that binary file. That's it.

Comment: I didn't mean or intend to patronise, but I do see how the way I write can project otherwise. I _was_ genuinely trying to offer advice to be helpful, and not to chastise, though I appreciate it was advice you didn't ask for. My apologies.

Comment: No worries. It is the internet. Since you wanted to know how I solved it, I will be posting it in the next few minutes.

Comment: I apologize too btw :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
######################################## BASH LIB #######################################
bash.string.replace() {
        local text="$1" find="$2" replace="$3";

        echo "${text}" | while IFS= read -r line; do 
                printf '%s\n' "${line//"$find"/$replace}"; 
        done 
}
######################################## BASH LIB #######################################

######################################## APPLE LIB ######################################
apple.plist.read() {
        local filepath="${1}"

        defaults read "${filepath}"                
}
apple.plist.convert.to.xml() {
        local filepath="${1}" tmp="${2}"

        # If second argument is passed, then we save the conversion to a new file rather than write over the original
        if [[ "${tmp}" == "true" ]]; then
            tmp="/tmp${filepath}"
        fi 

        if [[ "${tmp}" != "" ]]; then
            bash.cp "${filepath}" "${tmp}"

            filepath="${tmp}"
        fi

        plutil -convert xml1 "${filepath}"

        # We also output the content which can be supressed if desired by caller
        cat "${filepath}"                
}
apple.plist.convert.to.binary() {
        local filepath="${1}"

        plutil -convert binary1 "${filepath}"                
}
apple.plist.write() {
        local filepath="$1" text="$2"

        echo "${text}" > "${filepath}"

        apple.plist.convert.to.binary "${filepath}" # Not sure if this step is neccessary, if xml representation is enough. Not verified or tested without. 
}
apple.plist.read.search.replace.write() {
        local file="${1}" search="${2}" replacement="${3}"

        local updated=$(bash.string.replace "$(apple.plist.read "${file}")" "${search}" "${replacement}")

        apple.plist.write "${file}" "${updated}"
}
######################################## APPLE LIB ######################################


######################################## EXAMPLE ##################################
my.test.1() {
    apple.plist.read.search.replace.write "/tmp/com.apple.finder.plist" "/Users/" "/Home/"
}
######################################## EXAMPLE ##################################
```

Basically we call the function `plist.read.search.replace.write` with file arguments and what to replace which will read it to text, then we perform a replacement on that text, and then write that text back using `plist.write` which will also convert it from xml (which it will be) to binary using `plutil -convert xml1 "/path/to/file"`.

Rather than read using defaults read "..." we could in theory instad use plutil convert to xml but likely more expensive.

Comment: Now I have more logic concerning to apple.plist, like search a bunch of files and replace but this was the answer to the question.

Comment: I like your coding style.  It's very logical and clear.

Comment: Thank you, I've peeked on yours too. I like it! I wan't to figure out more about AppleScript and it's limitations. Is it possible to code AppleScript similar logic in JavaScript? I know you can execute js, but not sure how limited it is. Like control windows and what not. Other option I guess is Swift. AppleScript is nice for small things, but kind of difficult to do complex stuff. I've done some mostly through Keyboard Maestro but it can get pretty complex and difficult to maintain quickly. Also been considering hammerspoon, but why lua if JS possible?

Comment: AppleScript does have its limitations, but was only ever designed with a very specific remit. Are you familiar with _JavaScript for Automation_ aka "JXA" ? In case you hadn't heard of it, it's the JavaScript version of AppleScript, so will undoubtedly feel a lot easier to code in if you're already familiar with JS. Hammerspoon is underrated and lacks the fame of AppleScript (some well-known developers don't even know it exists). But it is impressive, uses low-level C APIs, and Lua is easy to learn. But, yes, Swift (and now SwiftUI) would be good to look into for software development.

Comment: @CJK Thank you! Do you think hammerspoon & lua would be more powerful / more feature rich than JXA? The only problem I have if one where to be able to develop something releasable, is how to bundle it. You'd have to require hammerspoon to be installed, or if possible bundle it in I guess. Lua is also another language to learn. Would you say everything is possible to do with Swift / Swift UI so maybe Hammerspoon would be a stray way?

Comment: I'd say, overall, Hammerspoon _is_ more feature-rich than JXA, and certainly a hell of a lot more stable. As you probably know, AppleScript has been left to rot by Apple, and each new version of macOS adds one or two new bugs that will never be fixed. JXA will inherit this, as well as problems with the JavaScriptOSA engine that isn't being updated, so is seeing a tendency to crash with the use of certain data types in JS-ObjectiveC. A pity, because JXA was more powerful than AppleScript. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ Swift can do everything Hammerspoon can do, although Hammerspoon simplifies stuff a lot making achieving certain things a lot easier. Swift _can_ do everything that AppleScript can do, since AppleScript only does one thing: construct and send AppleEvents. You can do this from Swift, but it's a fucking ballache and, for this reason, AppleScript is a godsend. So many Objective-C and Swift developers looking to send AppleEvents will still rely on AppleScript to do this. You can also write in C when writing Swift, so, in that way, it'll do whatever one can do in C (i.e. most things).

Comment: Came by this PDF and thought it could potentially be useful (although I haven't read it; I just saw the title and that it was fully downloadable so grabbed the link). [Swift In 24 Hours, Sam's Teach Yourself, 2nd Ed.](http://file.allitebooks.com/20171017/Swift%20in%2024%20Hours,%20Sams%20Teach%20Yourself,%202nd%20Edition.pdf)